# Meaning of $Gal(L/L)$ for some field $L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

In my notes it says $Gal(L/L)=1$ and I am confused on the notation clearly there is only one automorphism of $L$ that map all elements of the base field $L$ to itself namely the identity map. But what does  $Gal(L/L)=1$ mean? Shouldn't it be  $|Gal(L/L)|=1$ or is the $1$ some kind of notation to refer explicitly to the identity map?

Comment: I've seen $1$ used to refer to the trivial group before, e.g., unless I'm misunderstanding something, it's used in the Examples section of [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence) Wikipedia article. It makes as much sense as using $0$ to represent the trivial group in the context of abelian groups. But I accept that the notation may be nonstandard in the context of the question.

Comment: It's common to use $1$ (and not $\{1\}$) to denote the trivial group.

Comment: To make this even more confusing, note that the group $\{1\}$ is also a [zero object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/zero+object) and could therefore reasonably be denoted $0$. Really, these should be called "biterminal objects" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've always seen $\text{Gal}(E/F)$ represent the Galois group while $\lvert \text{Gal}(E/F) \rvert$ represent the order. If someone writes $\text{Gal}(E/F)=1$, I would assume they meant $\lvert \text{Gal}(E/F) \rvert=1$, but I am pretty sure $id$ is the notation for the identity permutation, not $1$.

Comment: $I_G$ for the identity of $G$ I've also seen

Comment: $e$ is often used too for the identity.

Answer (score 2):

What is meant to be expressed is that the Galois group is the trivial group, containing only the identity map.

The notation is sloppy. Even if $1$ were to stand for the identity, which is reasonable but perhaps a bit uncommon in that context, a correct way to write it would be $Gal(L/L) = \{1\}$.

You are right that a correct way to express the intended meaning would be $|Gal(L/L)|= 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the galois group is indeed a group, (informally of permutations of roots), when the group has only one element, it is a trivial group. The group contains only one element, the identity element guaranteed by the axioms.

All order $1$ groups are isomorphic, and it's reasonably common that people write a trivial group as $1$. This has similarity to the identity element of $\Bbb R^*$ or $\Bbb Q^*$ or $\Bbb C^*$ under multiplication, and so forms a trivial subgroup.

Also $1$ is commonly used to denote an identity matrix $1_{n\times n}$, when the dimension is understood from context, and so $n\times n$ is omitted.

$1$ is also used denote the identity map $1_A:A\to A$ of some set $A$, and again the when the set is understood from context the subscript is omitted, although $\operatorname{id}_A$ is also common. [Proof Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Identity_Mapping) mentions these as common symbols and has references there also.

Anyway given a wealth of examples where the number $1$ can be thought of as an identity element, it seems fitting to just call the trivial group $1=\{1\}$ with the trivial group operation inferred from context. This is probably an abuse of notation, but it's kind of convenient also.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a group, it is common practice to denote the identity of $G$ by $1_G$ or just $1$.  Writing $G = 1$ is an abuse of notation for $$G = \{1\}$$ which is intended to mean that there are no elements of $G$ except for the identity element.

Another way to interpret this is to choose once and for all a group consisting of a single element (there is up to isomorphism exactly one such group), and denote that group by the symbol $1$.  Writing $G = 1$ is an abuse of notation for $G \cong 1$.  This is the same as saying that $G$ is a group with one element.

I am not sure which abuse of notation is intended by the author of your notes, but the precise formulations of these abuses are logically equivalent.

Similarly, if $M$ is a module over some ring, the zero element of $M$ is usually written as $0$.  If this is the only element of $M$, one commonly writes $M = 0$ rather than $M = \{0\}$.